# Matching exact word with special character

Tags: regex

How can I match a word like `@hello#` without catching the word `@hello#1`? I have tried the `\\b@hello#\\b` word container but will not work with the special characters.

Comment: (@hello#)[^\d] Latter is 'not number'

Comment: I am trying to create a "find and replace" feature in an app which needs to search for words with special characters so is there a more general solution to this? This feature has a "match only whole words" checkbox.

Comment: How about surronding it with  [whitespace](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#chars) characters: `\s@hello#\s`?

Comment: That seems to catch only the word if it has whitespaces or linebreaks on each side

Comment: @Gravity123, this is definition of word (surrounded by whitespace)

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Don't forget to exclude `@hello#a`..`@hello#e`...  :D

Answer (score 0):

`@hello#(?!\d)`

this matches `@hello#` not followed by a digit.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/2UqRLH/1)